# How will the X ray diffraction pattern change if the crystal changes its lattice structure

Tags: x-ray-crystallography

A text says:

> An X - ray diffraction experiment is carried out on a crystalline solid having FCC structure at room temperature. The solid undergoes a phase transformation on cooling and shows orthorhombic structure with small decrease in its unit cell lengths as compared to the FCC unit cell lengths. As a result the 311 line of the XRD pattern corresponding to the FCC system will split into a triplet.

**Now this is what i could think about it:**
We know that the interplanar distance for an orthorhombic lattice is given as $$
d=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{h^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{k^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{l^{2}}{c^{2}}}}
$$ and using Bragg's law we can find the angle at which constructive interference occurs as $$
\sin \theta=\frac{\lambda}{2 d}=\frac{\lambda}{2} \sqrt{\frac{k^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{k^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{l^{2}}{c^{2}}}$$
using the values of$${h k l}$$$$={3 1 1}$$ we obtain the diffraction angle which is unique as given by the above equation. Beyond this I cannot understand what to do,how does any splitting occur, what am I missing.

Comment: `hkl` can be 311, or 131 or 113.  These are equivalent directions for the fcc lattice (in the sense that the distance between consecutive lattice planes is the same for each of these three directions).  Are these directions still equivalent when $a\neq b \neq c$?

Comment: @march, thank you. But since it is specified that the indices are(3 1 1), why should i choose the other combinations? My concepts are poor!

Comment: They're talking about the 311 line of the *fcc* pattern, but the 311 line is the same line as the 131 line and the 113 line, because the angles are the same (since the corresponding families of lattice planes are equivalent).  So talking about the 311 line of the *fcc* pattern is just a short-hand for *all* of these (and, by the way, any inversions of these numbers that are equivalent, like $(\bar{3}\bar{1}\bar{1})$.

Comment: Instead of "a text", please consider giving an actual reference.

Comment: @March ,much much thanks dear. Isn't it that the text should have put the indices inside angular brackets like <3 1 1> to indicate that it meant a family of directions?

Comment: @A curious mind,I would have but I could not, it's a type of course note.